# What version of iText does Coldfusion 9 use?

Tags: coldfusion, itext

It's not obvious what version of iText that ColdFusion 9 uses.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have coldfusion to look at, but usually iText leaves its version number in the PDF properties - try opening a coldfusion / iText-generated PDF in a text editor - or if you can see the iText .jar within coldfusion then try opening it with a .zip tool and looking at the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF which will usually contain the software version. (Why do you want to know, BTW?)

Comment: Because we have long sense integrated version 5 but just recently realized the licensing implications.  Now we want to go back to a lower version, so, might as well use what's already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ColdFusion 9.0.1 comes with "iText 2.1.0 (by lowagie.com)"

You can find a ColdFusion script to determine the version here: [http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-determine-version-of-itext.htm](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-determine-version-of-itext.html)l

Comment: Neat. Note that for iText 5 or later then it's now `com.itextpdf.text.Document` not `com.lowagie.text.Document`.

Comment: @Rup correct. So you can have the two versions of iText coexist if you load the libs of iText 5 or later with Javaloader without breaking cfpdf and other tags

Comment: @Rup - Thanks for mentioning it. It is an old entry. I just updated it to reflect the recent changes.

Comment: iText 2.1.0, from 2008, is also used by ColdFusion 10, 11 and 2016.