# While generating PDF in ColdFusion, Rowspan is not working properly for RTL direction (ex: Arabic)

Tags: pdf, coldfusion-9, right-to-left

I have a table structure in HTML where I have to use rowspan and RTL(Right To Left) direction for Arabic characters. But while converting this HTML to PDF,  rowspan is **not** working as expected. Assuming this is a bug in ColdFusion where an HTML with rowsapn and RTL direction is not working correctly.

Note that this is working fine for LTR (Left To Right) direction (ex: English Characters). But I need to use RTL direction since Arabic characters need to be displayed in PDF.

Any idea why this is not working?

Sample Code :

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" filename="C:\test.pdf" overwrite="true">

  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style>

  table, th, td {

      border: 1px solid black;

  }

  table#mainTable {direction:rtl;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<cfoutput>

<table id="mainTable">

  <tr>

    <td>Tariff</td>

    <td>Description</td>

    <td>Quantity</td>

    <td>Unit Price</td>

    <td>Amount</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td rowspan="7" >Customer Level Charges</td>

    <td>9999123456</td>

    <td>18.16</td>

    <td>6</td>

    <td>108.96</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>9999123456</td>

    <td>18.16</td>

    <td>6</td>

    <td>108.96</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>9999123456</td>

    <td>18.16</td>

    <td>6</td>

    <td>108.96</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Adjustments</td>

    <td colspan="4">-20</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>This Month Amount</td>

    <td colspan="4">1091.92</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Last Month outstanding Amount</td>

    <td colspan="4">0</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>Total</td>

    <td colspan="4">1146.51</td>

  </tr>

</table>

</cfoutput>

</body>

</html>

</cfdocument>
```

**Expected Result**

It should work as how it is working in Browser, screen shot attached.

[image]

Comment: You tagged your question with `itext` but it doesn't appear in your question. I suppose you made mistake. I will edit your question to fix this.

Comment: Coldfusion is using itext to generate pdf it seems so I tagged it

Comment: I just learned from googling that Adobe ColdFusion uses a 10 year old version of iText, 2.1.0 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646735/what-version-of-itext-does-coldfusion-9-use. I recommend that you use iText 7.1.1 + pdfHTML 2.0.1 instead, which was released last week. iText 2.1.0 most certainly contains many bugs that are solved in iText 7.1.1.